# SSD read-write failure with large amounts of data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, read-write

The software I am using sometimes requires, say, up to 36 hours of constant read-write (at max SATA II speed due to motherboard requirements) and CPU processing with a few gigabytes of program generated (numerical) data for use in scientific computing. Although Windows file system checkers and the PC manufacturer hardware assistant don't find anything wrong with the SSD, I am worried that the SSD might have been 'overused' and prone to non-functional issues with large amounts of data (for example the application stalled and no further program generated output, but Windows didn't crash or terminate the application). Replacing the SSD with the original HDD has none of these issues (from which the OS was originally cloned onto the SSD drive). With small amounts of data (and therefore shorter execution times), the application/OS/SSD is fine and I didn't have have this issue a while ago. I read that SSDs do not generally fail in this way, although there had often been spinning blue circle next to the mouse cursor (just after boot-up) and I had to re-install some other software more recently. I suspect that the fault may be with the original cloning of the OS rather than the SSD hardware. How can I find out if there really is anything physically wrong now with the SSD? The PC starts up and shuts down normally and no changes to the Windows Experience Index and 'normal use' of the PC!

Answer (score 0):

Modern hard disks and solid state disks support [S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology, aka SMART).

There are [countless](https://www.google.com/search?q=smart%20drive%20software&oq=smart%20drive%20soft&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.19284j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) SMART software tools you can use to check a drive's health.  I would check your SSD manufacturer's website for their SMART tool first, as they should, in theory, be able to determine the status of their drives the best.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the event logs, I do have a SSD on the bench that has Hard Disk like errors.  Typically SSD never fail or die outright.
You could use HHDScan to see if your speed is consistent, I do remember the old Intel SSD had a lagging issues.  maybe also post SSD/MB and spec info.

Comment: I can assure you they do fail commonly (but much less frequently then hdds). They are MORE LIKELY to fail catastrophically when they do fail then hard drives - especially ones with older/buggy firmware.

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. revealed good device health, so I am not looking into it further. Using TRIM might have cleared some residual junk up too. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Internal circuit of SSDs works on the capacitors and power supplies, these are drawback in the point of view of power surge or a power failure, because SSDs can corrupt some data due to power failure.

**But here some Free best tools, which can help to fix your troubles:**

- Crystal Disk Info
- Smartmonotools
- Hard Disk Sentinel
- Intel Solid-State Drive Toolbox
- Samsung Magician
- Crucial Storage Executive
- Toshiba SSD Utility
- ingston SSD Manager
- SSD Life
- SsdReady

**NOTE -** Download these softwares from their officially website only.